# Iterate through all document libraries and folders within libraries to set a column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am trying to create a PowerShell script/function that will iterate through all the Document libraries (and folders within them) to set a column value on every file on the SharePoint site.

The column is called Archive. It is a Yes/No Column. How do I set the column to No ($false in PowerShell, I believe)?

Comment: Was there a specific question?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I am looking for a way to do this

Answer (score 1):

The following PowerShell script for your reference.

```
##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://lz.sharepoint.com/sites/lz"
$UserName="lz@lz.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="****"
$libraryName="DL"

Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
$Web = $Ctx.web

#Get the List   
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($libraryName)
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get All List items
$ListItemsCAML = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$ListItemsCAML.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>"
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($ListItemsCAML)
$Ctx.Load($ListItems)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-host "Total Items Found:"$List.ItemCount
#Iterate through each item and update
Foreach ($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    #Set New value for List column
    $ListItem["Archive"] = $false
    $ListItem.Update()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
Write-host "All Items in the Library: $libraryName Updated Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Thanks, does this look in folders though?

Comment: Yes, using "RecursiveAll" to get all items contains the folders and items in folders.